# Can we add <div id="api"></div> in index.html of angular 7?

Tags: angular, html, azure-active-directory, angular7, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on angular7 and integrating it with Azure active directory B2C. So i have added `<div id="api"></div>` in index.html file of angular so it should display the fields which are coming from AAD side but when i am adding this and running the application, the components like `<app-home>`, `<app-header>`, `<app-footer>` etc are not loaded which i saw in index.html while inspecting in chrome.
Is there any other way to add **`<div id="api"></div>`** this? or i am doing this wrong?

```
 <body>
    <div id="api"></div>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
```

Comment: You may put whatever HTML you want in your `index.html` file (or any other file that loads Angular bundles). Can you post your console log for context? This should explain why Angular isn't bootstrapping itself.

Answer (score 0):

When running AD B2C user flows like Sign In, that will be always mandatorily a navigation to your AD B2C tenant url. So the SPA feeling can not be maintained anymore.

Because of this there is no sense to place the `<div id=“api”...` injection point into your SPA, just implement that as separate page.